# Must all 16 bytes of an x86 MASKMOVDQU instruction be valid memory?

Tags: assembly, x86, alignment, sse

When using the x86 `MASKMOVDQU` instruction, must there always be 16 bytes of writable memory at the target, even if some of the mask bits are zero?

For example, let's say that I write to address `0x12345FFC` using `MASKMOVDQU`.  The page at `0x12345000` is valid memory, but the page at `0x12346000` is not.  If the mask register is `0x00000000'00000000'00000000'FFFFFFFF`, will this `MASKMOVDQU` always work, or could an exception occur?

The Intel manual says the following about an all-zero mask, but doesn't mention the edge case I'm talking about:

> Behavior with a mask of all 0s is as follows:
>
> • No data will be
>   written to memory.
>
> • Signaling of breakpoints (code or data) is not
>   guaranteed; different processor implementations may signal or not
>   signal these breakpoints.
>
> • Exceptions associated with addressing
>   memory and page faults may still be signaled (implementation
>   dependent).
>
> • If the destination memory region is mapped as UC or WP,
>   enforcement of associated semantics for these memory types is not
>   guaranteed (that is, is reserved) and is implementation-specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the third bullet point. That specifically says exception may still occur, even if all masks are zero. Surely that implies exception may be generated for masked writes.

Indeed, the AMD manual is more clear on this issue:

> Exception and trap behavior for elements not selected for storage to
>   memory are implementation dependent. For instance, a given
>   implementation may signal a data breakpoint or a page fault for bytes
>   that are zero-masked and not actually written.

Comment: BTW, AVX `VPMASKMOVD` / `Q` *does* have fault-suppression from masking.  *Faults will not occur due to
referencing any memory location if the corresponding mask bit for that memory location is 0.*  There's no byte-mask version available, only D and Q.  It also doesn't have the NT hint.  (Note that `VMASKMOVDQU` still has the same semantics as the SSE version, and even still uses an implicit `[rdi]` store address instead of using the VEX prefix to allow two XMM regs and a full mod/rm-encoded address.  They obviously figured it wasn't useful enough to spend transistors on.)